# Using jQuery to make a div a button which affects other divs

Tags: jquery, html

I am programming a website as part of my dissertation and so far have been loving learning HTML and CSS however I now have a problem which I think jQuery can solve. I was just wondering if anyone could help me out with it please.

I have an image with `id="film_off"` a
And a movie in a div, `id="Firstworldvideo"`

I want to be able to click the image, which will make the video go opacity to go to zero.

```
<script> 
$(“film_off”).click(function(){
    $(“Firstworldvideo”).animate({
       opacity: '0'
    });
});
</script>
```

Am I close? Like I said, first attempt.
Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I missed off the  closing script tag </script> from the copy and pasting of the code.

Comment: you should add # before id's like this:$(“#Firstworldvideo”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your script

```
$(“film_off”).click(function(){
$(“Firstworldvideo”).animate({
opacity: '0'
 });
});
```

to

```
$("#film_off").click(function(){
$("#Firstworldvideo").animate({
opacity: '0'
 });
});
```

because you are using ID attribute so you have to add '#'. if you are suppose to use class attribute than you have to add '.' before any jquery events

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, just remember to use the hash mark (#) in your selectors.
You are in fact telling that when the element "film_off" gets clicked, the element "Firstworldvideo" will animate.
Alternatively you could use the on() function, that allows you to put a delegate selector right after the trigger event, like this: $("#film").on("click", "#firstworld", function(){....});
In this way you can use the $(this) selector referring to the #firstworld element.